# How do I filter through an array of arrays using an index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter

Im'm working on a JavaScript side prokect and I've got a json file with an array with arrays like this:

```
arr = 

{
  "values": [
    ["Form Factor", "OS"],
    ["Landscape", "Android 9\n(Source)"],
    ["Portrait", "Analogue OS"],
    ["Micro\nLandscape", "?"]
  ]
}
```

The first array with "Form factor" (index 0) are the headlines. If I want to get all the "form factors" from the arrays how would I do that?

I know that "Form Factor" has index 0 but how do i filter through several arrays at once with an index? in the end I want an array like

`results = ["Form Factor", "Landscape", "Portrait", "Micro\nLandscape"]`

I tried it like this:

```
const index = 0;
const result = this.arr.values.filter(function (eachElem) {
        return eachElem == index;
      });
```

But that just gives me back an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
arr.values.map(x => x[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't working because a) index isn't defined, you need to also put it as a parameter and b) in your case no element will be true.
I would use a traditional for loop in your case but surely if you want you can do it with es6 magic.

```js
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.values.length; i++) {
    result.push(arr.values[i][0]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use array.find() it's much easier and you can search for your element in your array:

const found = array1.find(element => element > 10);